# Mapping an array gives me undefined for some arrays because they're empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map-function

I'm using a map function to loop over objects and I want to access a property of an array inside the object called 'text'. however some arrays are empty so the text property would be undefined. thus, the computer throws me an error. I get this error

> 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined'

My approach is to use an iternary operator to check if item.myStocks[0].text exists before executing for each specific object that its looping over. but its not working I am using react.

```
 {this.state.filteredUsers.map((item)=>(
     <Table.Row  >
         <Table.Cell > <p style={{color:'black'}}> {item.myStocks[0].text? item.myStock[0].text : 'array has no texts... '} </p></Table.Cell>
         <Table.Cell> <p>datecreated </p>  </Table.Cell>
     </Table.Row>
     <Table.Row  >
        <Table.Cell > <p style={{color:'black'}}> text</p></Table.Cell>
        <Table.Cell> <p> datecreated</p>  </Table.Cell>
     </Table.Row>
```

Here is an example of what the mapped objects look like.. I am trying to access the first text of each objects array of 'mystocks'

```
{dateCreated: "2020-12-02T03:58:44.560Z", myUploads: Array(0), myStocks: Array(3), _id: "5fc727e84297219a0c59b408", email: "sam@yahoo.com", …}
{dateCreated: "2020-12-02T03:58:44.560Z", myUploads: Array(0), myStocks: Array(2), _id: "5fc730104297219a0c59b40d", email: "hip@gmail.com", …}
{dateCreated: "2020-12-02T03:58:44.560Z", myUploads: Array(0), myStocks: Array(0), _id: "5fc730ea4297219a0c59b412", email: "manny@gmail.com", …}
```

Comment: You could try to check the length of item.myStocks first. If it is greater than 0 then move on.

Answer (score 1):

try using optional chaining to verify also the myStocks[0] exist and also the text field

```
item.myStocks[0]?.text ? item.myStock[0].text : 'array has no texts... '
```

in your code the problem you can't approach the text field of non existing object, so you need first to verify it is exists.
without optional chaining it will look like

```
(item.myStocks[0] && item.myStocks[0].text) ? item.myStock[0].text : 'array has no texts... '
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to check if the array at `item.myStocks` is not empty, you can check its `length` inside the ternary. If it's greater than zero, you can access the first element `item.myStocks[0]`

Maybe you need to check, if `item.myStocks[0]` has a `text` property aswell. With this ternary nested inside the first ternary, if necessary.

`item.myStocks[0].text ? item.myStocks[0].text : 'has no text property'`

```
{this.state.filteredUsers.map((item)=>(


<Table.Row>
      <Table.Cell > <p style={{color:'black'}}> {item.myStocks.length > 0 ? item.myStock[0].text : 'myStocks array is empty...'} </p></Table.Cell>
     <Table.Cell> <p>datecreated </p>  </Table.Cell>
    

     </Table.Row>
     <Table.Row  >
      <Table.Cell > <p style={{color:'black'}}> text</p></Table.Cell>
     <Table.Cell> <p> datecreated</p>  </Table.Cell>
</Table.Row>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution. syntax is just a little tricky. i appreciate the help.

```
{ item.myStocks.length? item.myStocks[0].text : 'no text'}
```